# How to avoid particles passing through an object which is the emitter itself?

Tags: particles

As in the screenshot the particles are emitting from a specific portion of the bigsphere. I made a vertex group and assigned that group for the particle system so than the particles will emit from that specific part of big sphere. The issue i am facing is the particles now coming out is overlapping with the big sphere, some particles are coming out of the mesh which is not a part of the vertex group. I want these particles emit from that portion without overlapping with the mesh of bigsphere. There is also a pulsating animation applied to the vertex group with simple deform modifier.

I tried "size deflect" and also making the bigsphere a collision object but its not working.
Solutions?

Thanks [image]

Comment: What is the modifier order?

Comment: @vklidu There are multiple modifiers. Order is first the modifiers and then particle system

Comment: I don't think you can let collide particles with its emitter ... you would have to use a "dummy" -  exact copy of emitter with Collision physics hidden from rendering ... if it is not working share your simplified file to demonstrate your issue. You can use https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: THanks for the reply. I will try it

Comment: Since my model is a high poly mesh, it was bit difficult for me to use the duplicate. So I created a plane, applied collision,  and used it in front of the emitter. Even then the particles where passing through the mistake I did was I dint subdivide the plane, now the issue is solved.

Comment: Great it worked. Since this site is meant to be knowledge base ... Would be great if can write regular Answer so others can learn from you. Thank you